# Can I use scipy.optimize module with PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, scipy

I need to use scipy.optimize module after encoding some data with pytorch. However, scipy.optimize does not take torch.tensor as its input. How can I use scipy.optimize module with data with gradient path attached?

Comment: For questions regarding the `scipy` package, I insist you post the question on StackOverflow.

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/gngdb/a9f912df362a85b37c730154ef3c294b) works pretty well

Comment: I wrote [this new wrapper](https://github.com/gngdb/pytorch-minimize) as well because I forgot I wrote that gist.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround I'm currently using:

```
# model definition
class MLP(Module):
    # define model elements
    def __init__(self):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()
        self.hidden1 = Linear(2, 200)
        self.hidden2 = Linear(200, 100)
        self.hidden3 = Linear(100, 1)
        self.activation1 = LeakyReLU()
        self.activation2 = LeakyReLU()
 
    # forward propagate input
    def forward(self, X):
        optimize_flag = False
        if not torch.is_tensor(X):
            optimize_flag = True
            X = Variable(torch.from_numpy(X)).float()
        X = self.hidden1(X)
        X = self.activation1(X)
        X = self.hidden2(X)
        X = self.activation2(X)
        X = self.hidden3(X)
        if optimize_flag:
            return X.detach()
        return X
```

Just make sure when you are using scipy.optimize.minimize or any other function that uses the `x0` flag to input to pass in a detached tensor (i.e. `minimize(surrogate, x0=x.detach().numpy())`)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library to do just that: [autograd-minimize](https://github.com/brunorigal/autograd-minimize)

You can do something like:

````
from autograd_minimize.torch_wrapper import torch_function_factory
from autograd_minimize import minimize 

func, params = torch_function_factory(your_model, your_loss, X_train, y_train)

# Minimization
res = minimize(func, params, method='L-BFGS-B')
```
````